# Is it okay to use puppeteer to pre render SPAs?

Tags: puppeteer

Can puppeteer be used to do sever side rendering of SPAs in production?. Since puppeteer is running a headless version of chrome, will it have any performance impact on my production app, if i have thousands of users.

Comment: One option would be pre-render only _publicly visible_ pages (like a product page on an e-commerce store) and _aggressively cache_ them (like for an hour or two, depends on the how frequently the content is updated), either at your server node, at an intermediate node or using some reverse proxy caching service like cloudflare. For all other _private zones_ just use the SPA as-is in the browser